# Develop two Maven projects simultaneously in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am new to Maven, and trying to develop two projects, one of which depends on the other. I'm using Eclipse as my IDE, along with its integrated Maven features.

Let's say my two projects are named `foo` and `bar`, where `bar` depends on `foo`. Eclipse could help me generate the following `pom.xml`s:

foo:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.voichick</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
</project>
```

bar:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.voichick</groupId>
    <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.voichick</groupId>
            <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</project>
```

When I set up my project like this, it seems to work. There are no errors in Eclipse, and I can run classes in `bar` that depend on classes in `foo`. However, this success applies only when I use Eclipse's `Run As Java Application` option. When I try to run it as a `Maven install`, get the following output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bar 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.voichick:foo:jar:0.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.201 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-30T20:25:57-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/245M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project bar: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.voichick:bar:jar:0.0.1: Failure to find com.voichick:foo:jar:0.1.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

For some reason, it seems like Maven is smart enough to find `foo` when I'm running `bar` from Eclipse. However, when I try to build a jar using Maven, it fails.

I've noticed that if I replace `0.1.0` with `0.1.0-SNAPSHOT` (in both `pom.xml` files), it succeeds.

My question is: how is Maven intended to be used in this case? Should I use exclusively `-SNAPSHOT` versions until I'm ready to add my projects to the central repository? Do I need to do something fancy with modules? Or do I have some fundamental misunderstanding of Maven?

Comment: You need to `mvn install` the `foo` project first. This will install version `0.1.0` of `foo` into your local repository (which is typically available in your `~/.m2/repository` directory), where your build of your `bar` project will find it.

Comment: @SteveC Thank you! That solved my issue. I guess it _was_ a fundamental misunderstanding of Maven.